# Multidimensional array into POST call using foreach loop PHP

Tags: php, api, multidimensional-array

Looking for some advise with regards to multidimensional Arrays, pushing the vars into a POST call within a foreach loop.

I currently have a foreach loop containing an IF clause:

```
foreach ($responseData['data'] as $key => $value) {
  if (strtotime($value['attributes']['created_time']) > $currentDateMinusThirtyMinutes) {
  array_push($emails, $value['attributes']['email']);
  }
}
```

This is supposed to fetch the Email for all arrays which meet the condition of being created in the last 30 minutes.

However, now i am stuck, I need to fetch multiple other variables and call on a POST call similar to the below:

```
https://developer.example.co.za/{$PAGE}/create?reference={$ID}&currency=ZAR&amount={$AMOUNT}&firstname={$FIRST}&lastname={$LAST}&email={$EMAIL}&sendmail=true
```

What i need to know is, is there a better way to treat the foreach loop?

Is foreach the right way to go?

In essence I would need to run through each of the `$responseData['data']` returns and make a POST call to the above URL.

Any advise would be appreciated.

Comment: The right way to decrease your requests is to create an array with your "to keep" values then send a JSON or a stringify(`json_encode`) version to `https://developer.example.co.za/processJSON` and parse(`json_decode`) the JSON there and continue with intended logic. If you don't have access to `https://developer.example.co.za` then there is no other way, unless their api has some special entry for this kind of thing

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this by creating a Data_array which stored the values I required, then adding the POST call inside the foreach loop which then did the trick.

The foreach ended up looking like this:

```
foreach ($responseData['data'] as $key => $value) {
  if (strtotime($value['attributes']['created_time']) > $currentDateMinusThirtyMinutes) {
    $data_array[] = array(
     "id" => $value['attributes']['id'],
     ***add rest of vars you want***
    );
  ***Add POST call or whatever else you want to do***
  }
}
```

Thanks @darklightcode for pointing me to the idea of splitting out just the variables I wanted.